# Cannot fetch resource from one localhost server to another

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, localhost, package.json

I have two servers, one of them is Webpack server for React (`localhost:3000`), and another one is for Express server (`localhost:4000`). I read that I need to set up proxy in my `package.json` file. Okay, I did it. But it still doesn't work. I tried to set headers on `fetch` function. Still doesn't work. And no any errors in console.

Here's my code.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "newsfeed",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
  "dependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "run-p server start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node server_demo/server.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

class NewsBlock extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('localhost:4000/',{
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => this.setState({data}));
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.state.data}
              </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NewsBlock/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**server_demo/server.js**

```
const exp = require('express');
const app = exp();

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Listening on 4000'));

app.use(exp.static('./'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json({
        "glossary": {
            "title": "example glossary"
        }
    });

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the proxy field in `package.json`. Add [CORS middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) to your Express server.

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your server that it is okay to receive requests from somewhere else. You can use cross origin requests for this.

**Install CORS on your Express Server**

Use `npm i cors` to install cors on your server.

**Import into Server**

In your imports add `const cors = require("cors");`.

**Allow other servers to connect**

Then add this `app.use(cors());`

Bring it together your server should look something like this:

```
const exp = require('express');
const cors = require('cors'); 

const app = exp();
app.use(cors());

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Listening on 4000'));

app.use(exp.static('./'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json({
        "glossary": {
            "title": "example glossary"
        }
    });

})
```

That should do it. Hope this helps.